# Proof/disproof involving the floor function and inequality

Tags: logic

I am trying to prove $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, \Rightarrow\left(\exists \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{ +}, 0 \leq \epsilon<1 \implies  y=(n+\epsilon)^{2}-n^{2}\right)$.

I tried to pick an epsilon using the quadratic formula but I'm not able to show that it is between 0 and 1. Am I picking epsilon correctly or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You had a good idea to look for the quadratic formula.
$$y=(n+\epsilon)^2-n^2\iff \epsilon^2+2n\epsilon-y=0$$
By quadratic formula
$$\epsilon=-n\pm\sqrt{n^2+1}$$
The negative value is discarded, we are left with
$$\epsilon=-n+\sqrt{n^2+1}$$
Clearly $\epsilon\geq0$, it left to prove $\epsilon<1$.
Consider the right triangle with side adjacent to right angle mesuring $1$ and $n$, then the hypotenuse length is $\sqrt{n^2+1}$.  By the triangular inequality, the sum of two sides of a triangle must be greater or equal than the third side. The equality is obtain only if the three sides are co-linear. So
$$1 + n>\sqrt{n2+1} \iff 1>-1+\sqrt{n^2+1}$$
Hence $\epsilon<1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

For fixed $n$, $(n+\varepsilon)^2-n^2$ is an increasing function of $\varepsilon$, taking values between $0$ and $2n+1$ on $[0,1).$  By the intermediate value theorem, it assumes the value $y$ at some point in the interval.